# TypeError: The `dash_html_components.P` component (version 1.0.3) with the ID "Br(None)" detected a Component for a prop other than `children`

Tags: python, html, css, dashboard

I am new to Dash and HTML/CSS and am finding a problem with creating `<br>` tags in Dash.

I am trying to create a paragraph with text break in it using `html.Br()` but the error keeps telling me I haven't wrapped it in `children` even though I have. Here is my code:

```
external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

## CSS color codes ##
colors = {
'background': '#87CEFA',
'text': '#000000'
}


app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

## Creating HTML style ##
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='First Dash Server',
            style={
            'textAlign': 'center',
            'color': colors['text']
    }
    ),


    html.Div(children= 'Dash: A web application framework for Python.',
             style={
             'textAlign': 'center',
             'color': colors['text']}
    ),   


    html.Div(children=[
        html.H2('Information on server'),
        html.P('This is a Dash server and requirements are:'
                'X')]
    ),

   html.Div(children=[
    html.H2(('Introduction to the project'),
    html.P('In the process of idea building for this coursework I decided to host my visualisations on a dashboard using the Dash library in python.',
           html.Br(),
           'I started with a simple line graph using matplotlib'))]
),
```

This may be missing something in HTML but I cannot understand what is going wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am having the same issue right now. Did you fix this?

Comment: @Pythonista I did yes. You simple need to use the newline symbol `\n` in place of the html.Br(). Better yet use a markdown for your text using `dcc.Markdown` as this allows for better structure and formatting.